# React stone-cutter component enter and exit animations

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to react but have enjoyed working on a fairly simple masonry grid layout with filtering for a new website.

To achieve the masonry layout I'm using [Dan Trains stone-cutter component](https://github.com/dantrain/react-stonecutter) which looks amazing and perfectly suits my needs.

The component works as advertised to a point.. I currently have a functioning responsive masonry grid with custom child components (easily implemented and looks great!). The issue is when I try to add or remove items from the array that's feeding the grid with data. Instead of the enter and exit animations the app re-renders and I get a straight adding or removal of the elements.

Also if I set state in this component say from a button in the Tile component it causes a re-render.

If I remove stone-cutter and replace it with just a ul tag or even cssTransitionGroups tag the issue goes away.

My app is structured like so (where the Grid component is stone-cutter) :

```
<ProdGridApp>
<Filter/>
<Grid>
    <Tile>
        <Status/>
        <FavouriteButton/>
        <AudioPlyer/>
    </Tile>
</Grid>
</ProdGridApp>
```

When setting state (filtering or favouriting) I'm reaching up from the child components and setting it in the "ProdGridApp" component. When I do this with stone-cutter it triggers the app to re-render. Removing stone-cutter allows each component to only re-render if necessary.

My code for the main app (ProdGridApp) looks like this:

```
render() {
    const Grid = makeResponsive(measureItems(SpringGrid), {
        maxWidth: 1346,
    });

    const { enter, entered, exit } = enterExitStyle.foldUp;

    return (
        <div className="App">
        <Filter filterResults={this.filterResults}
                favourites={this.state.favourites}
                kits={this.state.kits}/>
            <Grid
                component="ul"
                className="prod-list"
                columnWidth={236}
                gutterWidth={40}
                gutterHeight={35}
                layout={layout.pinterest}
                enter={enter}
                entered={entered}
                exit={exit}
                easing="ease-out">
                {Object.keys(this.state.filterResults).map((keys) => {
                    return  <li key={keys}>
                                <Tile key={keys}
                                      index={keys}
                                      addFavourite={this.addFavourite}
                                      kits={this.state.kits}
                                      favourites={this.state.favourites}
                                      playStop={this.playStop}
                                      />
                            </li>
                    })}
            </Grid>
        </div>
    );
}
```

For what it's worth attached is a screen shot of the app in browser.
[Screenshot of masonry grid app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NVad.png)

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to move

```
const Grid = makeResponsive(measureItems(SpringGrid), {
    maxWidth: 1346,
});
```

out of the render method into a higher scope. This was answered by Dan Train over on the [stone cutter github page](https://github.com/dantrain/react-stonecutter/issues/26).